# Combining Swipe Gestures

Tags: android, swipe, gesture

I am building an app that requires a sequence of swipe. For example, a left swipe first, then swipe right then swipe up. If this combination is correct then user is sent to a new activity. I'm currently using this example 
http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118

Tried this code but can't seem to get the sequence correct

```
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    int action = direction;

    if (action == SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT) {

        if (action == SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT) {

            if (action == SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP) {
                //sent to new activity
                newActivity();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aviverma's answer was on the right track, but if you swipe RIGHT LEFT UP it will also work. If you want a well-defined sequence you should use an array to track the swipes already done and the next swipes necessary in the pattern.

```
int index = 0;
int[] pattern = new int[] { SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT, 
                            SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT, 
                            SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP };

public void onSwipe(int direction) {

    if (pattern[index] == direction) {
        // It's a match! Go onto the next one
        index++;
    } else {
        // Bad swipe, reset the user's swipe progress
        index = 0;
    }

    if (index == pattern.length) {
        // Reached the end of the pattern! We can perform the action now.
        // Reset index in case we need this again later
        index = 0;
        newActivity();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right. I realised the glitch and was trying to reset the swipes to get the match. But yours is a more optimised way. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Remove those nested if, because when you swipe `right` after `left` then it will search for `SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT` inside `onSwipe` method which is not present try using `boolean` values for that.

**EDIT: CODE (Just Giving you an idea how it may work)**

```
boolean RIGHT=false,LEFT=false;
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
int action = direction;

if (action == SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT) {
    LEFT=true;
 }

    if (action == SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT) {
    RIGHT=true;
 }

        if (action == SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP) {
            if(LEFT && RIGHT)
            newActivity();
 }

 }
```

Comment: This lets you swipe in an arbitrary order, not the correct one specified in the question.